Как установить тень для Button (Android)
Проблема в том, что эти атрибуты:
android:shadowColor=""
android:shadowRadius=""
android:shadowDy=""
android:shadowDx=""

делают тень для текста кнопки, а мне нужно именно для самой кнопки.
android:elevation=""

Так же пробовал так, но ничего не меняется.
Через android:background устанавливается дизайн для самой кнопки.
как правильно сделать тень и нужно ли делать для нее отдельный xml файл?

используйте elevation

@Style-7, я же написал, что когда его использую ничего не меняется, опишите пример его использования

Помимо назначения параметра elevation нужно отключить параметр stateListAnimator
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:elevation="20dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@null" />

Результат:


работает, а как сделать именно тень, не через elevation?

А чем вам не нравится через elevation?

я так понимаю все что можно настроить это только дальность от кнопки, а например цвет поменять я не могу?
